# How so set the jQuery default tab programatically?

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a jQuery UI tabs which represents the 7 week days. The only problem is that the first time the page loads, **Monday** is the active tab. I could also change the active page using **active: 3**, but I don't want the active tab to be fix. I'm providing a hidden field which has the day value.

```
@Html.Hidden("day", day)
```

So how do I set up the active page programaticaly?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $("#tabs").tabs();
  });
</script>
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want it fix, so I'm assuming you have the desired active day in a model. If so you can do this

```
$('#tabs').tabs({ selected: '@Model.ActiveDay' });
```

That's an old way of doing it (from an old project). [Based on the this documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) the (newest and) right way of doing it is this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ active: '@Model.ActiveDay' })
```

remember that it is zero-based so make sure that your `days` are zero-based too, if not then assign the value accordingly (e.g. do a -1 if your days starts with one)

Comment: My days are Monday, Tuesday, ..., Sunday. Do I need to convert them into a enum?

Comment: Seems like you're not using `DayOfWeek`, use that instead of creating your own enum.

Comment: Thank you so much. It looks like you have thought about every single thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are providing a hidden field, generated on the server-side and filled with a value from the server, and you then want to use JavaScript to read the value of the hidden field and set the active state of the tab accordingly, you might as well just set the active state in the HTML markup which generated on the server, before you send it down to the client.

You could do that by adding the following classes to the `li` which you want to be active from the start `ui-tabs-active ui-state-active`.

In addition you'd have to set `style="display: block"` on the `div` which is connected to the tab which you want to be active, and set the `div`'s `aria-expanded` attribute to `true` and the `aria-hidden` attribute to `false`.

That should to the trick.